# Check compatibility of a method with a given Delegate?

Tags: c#, .net, delegates, typechecking

In C# code, how do I check if a given method can be represented by a particular delegate type?

I first tried something, based on my Type knowledge, along the lines of:

```
// The delegate to test against.
void TargetDelegate(string msg);

// and...
var methodInfo = Type.GetMethod(..);  // obtain the MethodInfo instance. 
// try to test it 
typeof(TargetDelegate).IsAssignableFrom(methodInfo.GetType());
```

but that deals with only Types and not methods - it will always be false.

My inclination is to believe the answer lies in the [`Delegate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.delegate.aspx) Type, but I'm just wandering around the FCL at this point. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Not sure if this will help or not; I assume you've already seen this  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228976.aspx

Comment: @Adam, I don't need to create a delegate instance or invoke one. My need is for a simple check. However if somebody can extrapolate an answer I would be quite happy.

Comment: As Adam suggests, one way is to just call `CreateDelegate` with the `methodInfo` you have and see if it throws an exception (or returns null as the case may be).

Comment: Well I was thinking you could put a try catch around the create delegate.  If it succeeds, they're compatible, if not, they're not.  It's not terribly clean, but I'm not sure there's a better way.

Comment: I thought you don't want to create instance of delegate?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Checking a MethodInfo against a delegate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2221085/checking-a-methodinfo-against-a-delegate)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'd try:

```
Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(TargetDelegate), methodInfo, false) != null
```

This will try to create the delegate and return null on failure. If it return null, it should mean that the delegate was not able to be created. If it returns anything else, the delegate must be OK.

Answer (score 4):

I am not aware of a method in the reflection library that does that.

I don't think it would be too hard though. The rule for straightforward cases is that there must be a representation-preserving conversion from the method's return type to the delegate's return type, and there must be a representation-preserving conversion from each of the delegate's parameter types to each of the method's parameter types. That is, the compatibility relation is **covariant in return type and contravariant in parameter type**, as you'd expect.

There are more complex cases involving curried delegates but I think you probably don't want to get into those unless you are doing this to write a compiler for a functional language. (Are you doing this to write a compiler for a functional language?)

Comment: I'm writing a custom System.Attribute for classes that takes a method name as a string. I expect that method to be on that class, and to have a particular signature so I can take delegate instance from it.

Comment: I think we can dispense with the silly humility.  Instead of saying "I'm not aware of a method in the reflection library that does that", maybe just "there is no method in the reflection library..." :)

Comment: @Adam: Eric may be under the impression that he is fallible. :)

Comment: @Adam - I like that @Eric always makes a very sublet and humble argument. It's so much harder and more inspiring than anything else. Resist the temptation!

Comment: @Adam: It has nothing to do with humility, silly or otherwise. I recently wrote a blog article about looking at the bits of a double, and a commenter asked me why I didn't call BitConverter.DoubleToInt64Bits.  Because I didn't know there was such a method, that's why. I'm not an expert on the BCL, and in particular I am not an expert on System.Reflection; I barely ever use it. (I party directly on the metadata tables and skip the middleman.)

Answer (score 1):

There may be a more elegant way, but you could try creating the delegate, and check for an exception:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228976.aspx

Comment: If you're going to this route its probably better to use the signature `Delegate.CreateDelegate Method (Type, MethodInfo, Boolean)` and pass false for the boolean. Then check for null instead of an exception.

Comment: Looks like Gabe beat me to it :)

Comment: And then Bala changed his. Pretty amusing. Guess I should have put it as an answer instead of a comment

Answer (score 0):

say you have

```
   private delegate int MyDelegate(string a);
   private int Foo(string a)
   {

   }

   MethodInfo mFoo = this.GetType().GetMethod("Foo");
   var @delegate = Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof (MyDelegate), mFoo, false);
   if(@delegate!= null)
   {
      // compatible
    }
    else
    {
       // not compatible
    }
```