# How to check signature compatibility between EventInfo and MethodInfo in c#?

Tags: c#, reflection

```
public static bool CheckSignature (EventInfo eventInfo, MethodInfo methodInfo)
{
//check signature    
}

public class MonoMethod
    {
        public Component target;
        public string methodName;

        public static Delegate CreateDelegate<T>(MonoMethod monoMethod)
        {
            if (monoMethod.target == null || string.IsNullOrEmpty(monoMethod.methodName))
            {
                return null;
            }

            //Check compatibility before CreateDelegate
            //...if false, return null

            return Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof (T), monoMethod.target, monoMethod.methodName);
        }
    }
```

I want to check the **signature**(aka **ReturnType** and **ParameterInfo**) between an `EventInfo` and a `MethodInfo` before creating delegate from that methodInfo .
I can get the **ReturnType** and **ParameterInfo** from `MethodInfo` but not from `EventInfo`.
Is there anyway to achive?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're trying to do, but `EventInfo.GetRaiseMethod()` ["Returns the method that is called when the event is raised."](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/1a4k4e35%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Probably you want to compare this one.

Comment: @Christian.K nope. I want to know if this method can be added to target eventHandler during runtime.

Comment: OK, last [attempt](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2221085/21567) before I give up ;-)

Comment: Hmm... have you actually looked at the answer I linked? :-) I think you simply need to do "nothing", but call the [CreateDelegate-overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/db68wfw4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) that doesn't throw, but _returns null_, when the signatures don't match.

Comment: @Christian.K Thanks! Thought it might throw! :P

Answer (score 1):

For `EventInfo`, the `EventHandlerType` will be a delegate.

Look at the `Invoke` method via reflection to find the signature.

Then simply compare with the `MethodInfo`.